# Configure SVN/TFS to monitor folder and silently check in file changes (for auditing purposes)?

Tags: svn, tfs, monitoring, auditing

(also posted at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/456769/looking-for-app-service-to-silently-capture-file-changes-in-website-like-svn-bu), but realised there would be more SVN/TFS users here)

Bottom line question:

- Is it possible to create an SVN/TFS repository with an unattended service running that silently checks in all changes made to files in a target folder along with the username of the changer? It must be completely invisible to the person making the file changes.

Here's the background to my question:

A number of people deploy changes to our ASP.NET website ... designers deploy HTML and CSS changes, .NET developers deploy ASPX, DLL files, graphic designers deploy images, etc etc.

*In theory* all these deployments are done in a very controlled way - source code is maintained in SVN, deployment packages are created and version controlled, deployments are tested first on a pre-production site, deployments to live are documented. *In theory* we always know what files were changed, when, why & by who.

However, sometimes someone makes a change directly on the live site and bypasses all the procedures. Usually this is because of some emergency. Sometimes a change is made that causes a problem on the site ... and no-one owns up to it!

So what we are looking for is some kind of unattended service that captures all file changes to specific folders on the server. It should "check in" file changes as they happen, i.e. capture the new version of the entire file, and also capture the Windows login of the user. In other words, every file gets a history of changes made to it, just like SVN, TFS etc. We should be able to do a diff between versions in the file's history. 99% of what it captures should be changes made through the proper procedures - but it should also contain the 1% that are not.

To be clear - we are not looking for a service that sends "file integrity" alerts, like OSSEC. We just want every file change to be captured, so in the event of something going wrong we can check the change log and figure out what was done outside of the usual procedures. Also, it obviously should be completely automated - requiring the users to follow an additional procedure is not what we are after here !

Also, periodically taking backups and then looking for differences between them is not what we want, because this would not tell us who made the change.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible to do so, I strongly encourage you to fix the root cause of your concerns - not the symptoms.

> However, sometimes someone makes a change directly on the live site and bypasses all the procedures. Usually this is because of some emergency. Sometimes a change is made that causes a problem on the site ... and **no-one owns up to it**!

(emphasis mine) This is a **huge** problem which you need to address. Access to the live site should be locked down very tightly (only release managers should have write access to the server - or better yet, an automated deployment process), and an "emergency" change should still follow the same general workflow to get into production - just accelerated.

Each release to your live site should be a single package (or a scripted process, repeatable process which varies only in which build you tell it to push to the live site), and the promotion coordinated by a fixed person/group of people. Nothing goes live without following the process (including signoff from clients/stakeholders and change managers), and the promotion is done the same way, every time, by the same people.

Right now - by your own admission - you have no accountability. As long as people *can* get away with something, they *will attempt to do so.* Either with malicious intent, or because "following the process takes too long/is too hard."

Short version: rather than *enabling* this behavior by working around it (with the solution you're seeking here), *stop it from happening in the first place* so that you don't need to clean up after the fact.

> Also, periodically taking backups and then looking for differences between them is not what we want, because this would not tell us who made the change.

I don't see how your proposed solution would give you the audit trail you need. The service would just commit the changes that were made, not who made those changes. Could you trace the source of the changes by using Windows security logging & maybe NTFS auditing? Maybe, maybe not.

How would this service handle merging conflicts? In SVN, you can only commit if your WC is at the HEAD revision, so you'd have to update, then commit. What happens if there are other changes to those same elements which need to be merged?

I would recommend looking into a monitoring service such as Tripwire to watch for changes made to your live site, but that still may not tell you *who* made changes or *why* - but you can at least get notified very quickly if it happens.

Comment: Access to the live site is already limited to a very small set of people, and we do have procedures. We are not dealing with a situation where there is no control in other words. We can't limit access to just 1 person - its not practical. What I am looking for is some kind of auditing for the 1% of occaisions where procedures and accountabilities are bypassed.